# Lower-case all text in a datatable, or lower-case all text on a page to use css text-transform: capitalize?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

I've run into the problem that CSS cannot use `text-transform: capitalize` on text that's already capitalized. Unfortunately the text being returned from my database is capitalized in many cases. Rather than putting a `LOWER(X)` ahead of every single field I'm requesting from the database, or call a JS function on every field, it seems like it'd be easier to use a solution that just targets the entire datatable returned, and then use `text-transform: capitalize` in the page's CSS.

Any suggestions for an easy way to do this? Alternatively, a way to target all the text on the page (JS, perhaps?) and lowercase it, then have the CSS part recapitalize would be fine. I'm looking for the easiest possible solution, whatever that may be (and rewriting a large number of queries simply isn't it.)

Comment: you can use some built in functionality for the .ToUpper(), .ToLower, or you can write your own `ToProperCase` I have written one at my last project but unfortunately I do not have the code with me. have you looked at `using Microsoft.VisualBasic``namespace` see if there is a ProperCase function.. look at running a `SWL Server Function` that will ProperCase all your data in the DB or that particular field

Comment: Ben, do you want to see a few examples on how to do this using SQL ?

Comment: ToUpper and ToLower have the problems that they have to be called on a field level. 

DJ: I know how to do LOWER(X) in a select statement--it was stated in the original question. :) If you know a way to do a blanket LOWER against all returned fields, that would be useful, however.

Comment: Ben how many fields are you returning ..? can you show an example edited in your original question. I have something i just tested with "FOR KING AND COUNTRY" for example that returns "for king and country" I will post that and you can test it out as well as play around with the code you will still need to write a bit of code but I would love to see / know how many fields your are working with

Comment: Data should *always* be normalized before inserting into the database.  If you've already got data that's in the incorrect format, then normalize it on the way out of the database.

Comment: Ben please show what your `Select Query` looks like so that I can help you adjust your select statement..

Comment: DJ: The query is ridiculously long. It's easy to rewrite and I already know how to do it, I was just wanting to see if there was a smarter approach. Thanks for the assistance, though. :)

Comment: Without knowing your query that's the best I can suggest from a basic one field Query.I hope that this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ben you can use this Select Query against your DataTable 
you will need to adjust the field(s) based on your Table. I am only showing this using 1 field name called `DESC`

```
select
    DESC =
    -- Adjust the length of your filed(s) for example DESC is varchar(500)
    convert(varchar(500),
    upper(substring(DESC,1,1))+
    lower(substring(DESC,2,499)))
from
    YouTable Name
```

Comment: DJ: That is an approach that works. ToLower() also works, as does LOWER(x) in the SQL query itself; I never had a question about how to target single variables, as I know how and have done that in practice. My question was just as to whether there was a way to use a command, either in the SQL query, against the datatable, or against the page text as a whole that would do the trick all in one shot. Based on the responses to the question, there doesn't seem to be a way to do that. With that in mind, I'll edit the SQL queries as the simplest approach to doing so.

Comment: I have a query that you can run against your data table I will my answer one sec

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to do that is incorrect. Lowercase what’s in your database, easier or not.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be to change the data in your database so that you don't have capitalized strings, and let CSS do its thing. In any case, doing it on JS/CSS alone is not the way to go.

Comment: I can't change the data in the database--this is simply one application of many and for whatever reason the ones that write the data do so as upper case.

Comment: you're down to `LOWER()`ing your fields in the DB requests then, I'm afraid -- it's much more efficient that way than doing so on each client browser (due to caching etc on the server side)

Comment: That sounds like a totally bad design / application Ben.. well use the build in functionality convert / display the data in proper case then

Comment: DJ KRAZE: I don't disagree. I'm new to the company, however, and all of this was in place long before my arrival. I'm just trying to figure out the most efficient way to deal with the situation. I've no problem with rewriting all my SQL queries if need be, but making sure that was necessary first seems like a better idea than just doing the grunt work while thinking "If only!" :)

I'm also not clear on why the question was downvoted; I made it clear in the question that I knew how to use LOWER(x) and was looking for a better solution. That there isn't one doesn't make it a bad question.

Comment: have you looked at trying to do ToTitleCase ? I will test something out real quick and post you a way of doing this ok

Comment: ToTitleCase is a field-based command as well, unless there's a way to target all the text on a page that I haven't been able to find. What I was really hoping for was either a single command to lower an entire datatable or a way to target all the text on a page and lower it via JS or some other method, then re-capitalize via CSS. Any approach that requires targeting each individual field will probably be less efficient than rewriting the SQL statements anyway.

Comment: Ben you would need to do that in a `foreach loop` or a `for loop` or a `while loop` also you will need to use `System.Globalization` namespace as well as `using System.Threading;` writing a loop may seem like it takes a long time to process but I think that it would do it really fast.. look at the example and from there you can do it on a `char` by `char` basis as well in a foreach loop